# Comparing a variable to 2 values

Tags: php

I have a variable `$var` which must be either *one* or *two* and if it's not then throw an error

```
if($var != "one" && $var != "two")
{
    exit('$var must be either one or two');
}
```

This works. However as `$var` is a string and can only hold one value not both, so I'm wondering if it's not logical to write like that?

Comment: If your variable has to be one of two values, it would generally be more logical to accept/create and store it as a boolean value rather than a string.

Comment: it's ok, a variable normally contains some variable value, not a constant value. One example: `if ($phone_origin != 'Shop' && $phone_origin !='Second Hand') { exit("The phone origin is unknown!"); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's fine, the illogical code would be `($var == 'one' && $var == 'two')`

You are checking that it's not one or two - a variable can 'not be' an endless amount of values.

Answer (score 3):

You can try it like this:

```
$possible = Array( "one", "two" );
if(!in_array($var, $possible) ) {
    echo "$var can be either of: " . implode($possible, ", ");
}
```

This way, you can later include more values to be checked against.

Comment: @Sirko Whoops. ^_^ PHP must change to `camelCase` style too. XD

Comment: You forgot a "!" in front of in_array

Comment: one liner: `if (!(in_array($var, array('one','two')))) exit('error');`

Comment: @Pedro yes, and you can also write an entire file of PHP code on a single line. But the readability will be close to zero...

Comment: @PedroL. But I've been using `Array` for a long time now, and it has never failed me yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( !( $var == "one" || $var == "two" ) )
{
    exit('$var must be either one or two');
}
```

This would be the way i would check to see if $var container either "one" or "two". As stated in other answers there is alternatives, but why over complicate things?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Simplified readability. It's like writing `x(5+5x)` or writing `(5x+5x*x)`.

Comment: Once the extra-parentheses are removed, you end up with exactly the same code as the one in the question.

Comment: @Incognito I think this makes it more difficult to understand.

Comment: Sam's solution would work fine. I think it really boils down to what's intuitive to the programmer at the time of working out the condition in the head. This is a case where the knowledge of De Morgan's laws really helps: [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) Basically, !(x && y && z) is the same as (!x || !y || !z) and !(x || y || z) is the same as (!x && !y && !z)

Answer (score -1):

Its completely logical to write what you have written!

What you are writing is, IF $var is not one (which means it can still be anything else) AND IF $var is also not two (Its at this point you've ruled out both the possibilities), THEN throw the error!

Also, id recommend you to use `throw new Exception('Error Message');`